# How to retrieve users data android from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please guys, does anyone know how to retrieve data from Firebase when the user save something then he wants to retrieve it.

This is the saving code

```
        fireapp=new Firebase("https://training-a3c4e.firebaseio.com/User");
        btn1=findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ed1=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2=findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String data1=ed1.getText().toString();
               String data2=ed2.getText().toString();

                Firebase getRoot=fireapp.child(data2);
                // Firebase.goOffline();
                getRoot.setValue(data1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This `new Firebase("...");` is an incredibly old syntax for the Firebase Database. Consider upgrading to a more recent version, so that you can follow along with the current documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
fireapp=new Firebase("https://training-a3c4e.firebaseio.com/User").child(data2);
fireapp.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // your data will be here in dataSnapshot

        }
    });
```